# manipulation of mac os x installation package on debian linux

Tags: linux, macos, installation, debian

Can it be done?

I need to create an installation package for OS X (10.5 and on) from a Debian machine according to configuration given at request time (this configuration will change configuration files that are a part of my package and are installed together with the application). Is there any way of changing or manipulating with an already made (using the OS X PackageMaker) package contents?

I did see in previous posts a claim that OS X packages can only be made (packaged) and edited on Apples. Is there a way around it?

I've tried manipulating with no success, the Flat package format and the meta-package (OS X 10.3).

Comment: What configuration files do you need to change? The `whatever.pkg` file is really just a folder.

Comment: @WilliamJackson - The configuration files used are my own apps files. The pkg is indeed a folder, yet, no archiver I've tried managed to extract the files and then package it back correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while, but in the end I managed to pack it as flat package wrapped as tar, and manipulate the content using a script that simply replaces some dummy files that were packaged along just for that purpose. Not a pretty one, but it worked by the time we needed that, and to be honest, we haven't gone back to dealing with that in order to find a nicer solution. If anything changes, I will (eventually) update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for certain if it can be done, but BitRock's InstallBuilder can [generate OS X packages on Linux](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/docs/installbuilder-userguide.html#_requirements).  Perhaps there is some means to un-package the artifact and then supply that as input to InstallBuilder.

Comment: I'm baffled why the question ended up on `superuser` instead of serverfault.com or even SO as the solution will definitely involve programming.

Comment: Took a look at the link you supplied, it actually looks nice and might have suffice as the answer if not for the very very high price. We can't afford it here... I was wondering the same about why the question ended up here

Comment: @NightRider If your package is for an open source project, they do offer free licenses http://goo.gl/rGFmI.  Otherwise, I agree, it isn't cheap.

Comment: Have seen it :o), but unfortunately I can't claim to be working on an open source project... So I am still trying to come up with some idea to solve my problem